# Alternatives to prevent dependencies changes in distribution?

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language

I'm sending a client a program made using Python and Kivy. I packaged everything using PyInstaller and NSIS for the installer, but in both options the images and sounds folders stay fully accessible.

Is there any way to prevent further changes in the software images after the installation? Maybe a different way of loading the images to the kivy widgets?

Currently I'm loading all the images with something like:

```
source: "images/background1.png"
```

I tried using PyInstaller `-F` and `--onefile`, but the .exe still requires the dependencies folder.

Comment: You can add the images to the .exe and access them later using the `sys._MEIPASS` variable. More, in the PyInstaller manual... ;o)

Comment: When you say you are using `PyInstaller -F`, are you also providing a `.py` file name or a `.spec` file name?

Comment: @JohnAnderson yes. The command was like: python -m PyInstaller -F main.spec

Comment: Be aware that when specifying a `.spec` file on the `PyInstaller` command line, most of the provided command line options are ignored. So your `-F` is among those ignored. Check the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html).